# Can I remove cakephp default folders?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working on cakephp project and I have found that there are many folders which are not using. I am wandering, if we can remove them
without affecting the website. Those folder are

```
app/Config/Schema
app/Console
app/Controller/Component
app/Lib
app/Model/Behavior
app/Model/Datasource
app/tmp
```

I have checked that removing these folders does not affetc the website.. Can I delete these folders from server?

I have also search it on google but I did not get proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, some empty folders can be safely removed.
Do NOT remove the tmp folder though.
Also, the console folder should never be empty and contain the cake scripts, at least.

Comment: about the console folder: if one just needs to run the website and doesn't use the console and shell features is it safe to remove the folder?

Comment: @arilia yes, you can remove it

Comment: Of course. But it would not hurt to keep them either. Don't make this rocket science.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot remove these folders as there are important to the entire framework of cakephp.

From their website:

"The app folder will be where you work your magic: it’s where your application’s files will be placed."

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-folder-structure.html